# TeamCity integration with Sitecore CMS

Tags: sitecore, teamcity

Is there any out-of-the-box feature available to integrate Sitecore CMS with TeamCity? I checked the list of runners available, but I don't seem to find any.

My customer has a ASP.NET project and uses Sitecore CMS for the website. I am trying to build a pipe to automatically trigger a build at a certain time of the week and deploy to Sitecore. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying Sitecore is much like deploying any standard .NET web application, except for the content.

I've written a blog post on automating your deployments with [TeamCity and Team Development for Sitecore (TDS)](http://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/automating-sitecore-deployments-with-teamcity-and-tds/). You can ignore the TDS-specific information if you are looking just to push the code. However, if you plan on deploying content items immediately, TDS is helpful for that.

There is also a post by Jason Bert that covers using [OctoDeploy with TeamCity and TDS](http://www.jasonbert.com/2013/11/03/continuous-integration-deployment-with-sitecore/) for continuous deployment.

You may want to just start by setting up a standard .NET MSBuild step and then deploying the build of the code out to your site. That will get you started and then you can begin to tweak from there and choose which other tools will fit your needs.